# Multivariate Newton Series?

Tags: combinatorics, numerical-methods, binomial-theorem, interpolation, newton-series

Does a multivariate expansion of the Newton series exist?
If so what is its formulae?

In the scalar case we have that by expansing around $0$ if $x \in Z$ then:

\begin{equation}
f(x) = \sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{m!} \Delta_1^m f(x)|_{x=0}(x)_m
\end{equation}

where $\Delta_1^m$ is the forward finite difference appleid $m$ times one step ahead and $(x)_m$ is defined as follows $(x)_m = \prod_{n=0}^{m-1}(x-n)$, i.e. the falling factorial

Does a multivariate form exist, analagously to the Taylor Expansion? Say for instance to expand $f(x,y)$?